# Does the Glass Development Kit (GDK)) support RenderScript?

Tags: google-gdk, renderscript

Do you know, the Glass Development Kit (GDK)) supports RenderScript or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it does. You can try [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-renderscript-on-android--mobile-9154). Also, see [Renderscript support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20172491/renderscript-support): I consider [Tony's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20172491/renderscript-support/20249399#20249399) as an authoritative answer.